# Подскажите, как убрать слайдер swiper, при ширине экрана менее 768px и содержимое слайдера осталось?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

**Уже где только искал, как сделать так, чтобы слайдер swiper отображался только с планшета и десктопа... код на js
**

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    // Default parameters
    slidesPerView: 0,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    // Responsive breakpoints
    breakpoints: {
        // when window width is >= 360px
        360: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 0,
        },
        // when window width is >= 768px
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10
        },
        // when window width is >= 1378px
        1378: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 60
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .swiper1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Можно спрятать стилями